# Vim, custom tab and vertical split organization on open

Tags: vim

Say the files in my working directory are `src/example.c`  `src/second.c` `src/third.c` `include/example.h` `include/second.h` `include/third.h`.

I want to open vim in a way that automatically opens **three** tabs (example, second and third), where each tab contains a vertical split screen between a `.c` and corresponding `.h` file. Like the following commands would.

```
:tabnew include/example.h | vs src/example.c
:tabnew include/second.h | vs src/second.c
:tabnew include/third.h | vs src/third.c
```

Is there a way I can make a special script that will do this when I open vim?

It is safe to assume files will have the same name.

Ideally, this would happen from a shell script rather than modifying my `.vimrc`, if that is possible.

Comment: This is a very peculiar workflow, unlikely to be reused over and over. Since you want this to happen from a shell script, [Doktor OSwaldo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73877017/5825294) is probably the only way to go. (Vim has an `-O` option to open files in vertical split and `-p` to open them in different tabs, but these two options don't work together as you'd hope.)

Comment: On the other hand, with the correct plugins, arranging windows manually could require far less keystrokes than writing a command line and be much faster. Let me know if you are interested in such an answer, and I will show you the plugins I'd use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well if you want to do that, you clearly need a way to execute vim commands from your shell. Lets see if the vim application supplies that, by using the help command which we should ask first for every shell command:

```
?> vim --help | grep cmd

--cmd <cmd>           Execute <cmd> before any config
+<cmd>, -c <cmd>      Execute <cmd> after config and first file
```

So all that is needed is to chain these commands:

```
vim -c 'tabnew include/example.h' -c 'vs src/example.c' -c 'tabnew include/second.h' -c 'vs src/second.c' -c 'tabnew include/third.h' -c 'vs src/third.c'
```

as @Enlico pointed out in the comment, you should use `edit` or `e` instead of `tabnew` in the first command, else you will get 4 tabs. But I used your commands so you can see how easily you would have been able to solve this by reading the `--help` output.

Comment: You should change your first `tabnew` to `edit`, otherwise you end up with 4 tabs, the first of which is on a new unnamed buffer.

Comment: @Enlico you are of course right and I will add it to the answer. Thank you. But my intention was mostly to show how easy that question is solved by reading the help

Comment: "But you can see how easily you would have been able to solve this by reading the `--help` output" PROTIP: don't ever mention that. ;-)

Comment: @romainl feel free to remove it if you think it is necessary. But I stated it without any anger at all. I just want to help people to help themselves so you don't have to ;-) Jokes aside I am not yet so frustrated about SO to be annoyed by that, so I hope 
jzimmerman can take it as honest advice instead of mocking him.

Comment: For some reason I thought it would only let you use one command not multiple. Thanks for the help, will definitely look harder next time!